# How do browsers implement event polling?

Tags: browser

So I am trying to get an idea of how browsers are internally implemented. The browser must poll the event queue for events, but I am wondering how frequently this is done or If there is some sort of pattern/known solution to go about this?

You clearly can't do

```
while(1) {
    //check the event queue for events 
}
```

B/c that would lock up the entire thread and the browser uses a single-threaded execution model in which it checks the event queue for any events, if there is an event in the event queue - then it executes it. (At least that's how I understand it)

Comment: Sockets are polled for events using [poll(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or other similar method. Also see [Event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop).

Comment: @DanD. Thanks! Wish I had enough rep to upvote